# Text color on Angular Material mat-chip

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I have a `mat-chip-set` and several `mat-chip` objects with a custom `product-chip` class:

```
<mat-chip-set>
  <mat-chip class="product-chip" *ngFor="let category of categories">
    {{category}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-set>
```

my css is:

```
.product-chip {
  background-color: pink !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

The result is that the chip background color IS pink like I want, however the text color is still black.

How can I make the text color of the `mat-chip` objects white?

See StackBlitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzhkmg?file=src/app/chips-overview-example.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would edit the variables used.

`style.css`

```css
.mat-mdc-standard-chip {
  --mdc-chip-label-text-color: #fff;
}
```

Also, check what other options do, to keep styling consistent when chips are in some other state (disabled).

```css
.mat-mdc-standard-chip {
  --mdc-chip-elevated-container-color: #e0e0e0;
  --mdc-chip-elevated-disabled-container-color: #e0e0e0;
  --mdc-chip-label-text-color: #fff;
  --mdc-chip-disabled-label-text-color: #212121;
  --mdc-chip-with-icon-icon-color: #212121;
  --mdc-chip-with-icon-disabled-icon-color: #212121;
  --mdc-chip-with-trailing-icon-disabled-trailing-icon-color: #212121;
  --mdc-chip-with-trailing-icon-trailing-icon-color: #212121;
  --mdc-chip-with-icon-selected-icon-color: #212121;
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzhkmg-dk3hsm?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if there is a place where all of those custom variables are listed for all Angular Material Components?

Comment: I don't think such internal variables are documented, as they are probably subject to change. I find them using inspector tools. Another possibility would be to use theme and theme generators instead https://material.io/blog/material-theme-builder.